# htaccess preventing Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I just installed a wordpress blog which will stand as a standalone blog for an otherwise static site. The blog is finished and when I view it all appears fine....until a permalink (to view the single post) is clicked. Upon click, the user is redirected to the homepage. I believe the htaccess file is causing this. You can try this out by viewing the the blog site: http://nathantrotter.com/blog/

Here is my htaccess file (from the root directory of the site, the wp blog directory does not have one)...do I need to create another line to make the blog permalinks work? If so, what?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/index.php
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=products&metal=$1
RewriteRule ^services/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=services&sub=$1
RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=about&sub=$1
RewriteRule ^facilities/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=facilities&sub=$1
RewriteRule ^press/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /viewPress.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?p=$1
```

Comment: Just like adding a new custom post type, resetting the WP permalinks fixed this...not sure why, but it worked!

Answer (score -1):

This is not an htaccess issue. Simply go into the WP permalinks settings page and update your existing permalinks. That fixes it.

Comment: This changes your htaccess... You just found a way to update htaccess «correctly». Perhaps the htaccess inside your wp directory.